# KKT conditions , inequality constraints

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am having trouble finding finding the KKT points of the following problem.
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\min \max &{\tau^2}
\\
\text{subject to} & \tau \leq 3 l_u ^2\\
& \tau \geq \gamma + l_u + 2\\
& \tau \geq \frac{3(\gamma - l_u)^2 + \|A\|^2}{C}
\end{array}
$$

where $l_u, \gamma, C, \|A\|^2$ are given constants.

The Lagrangian is
$$
\mathcal{L}(\tau,\lambda, \mu, \omega)=\tau^2 + \lambda (\tau - 3 l_u ^2) + \mu (-\tau + \gamma + l_u + 2) + \omega (-\tau +\frac{3(\gamma - l_u)^2 + \|A\|^2}{C}) \quad \lambda, \mu, \omega \geq0, 
$$
KKT Conditions:
$$
\begin{align}
& L_{\tau}=2 \tau + \lambda - \mu -\omega =0 \\
& \lambda (\tau - 3 l_u ^2) = 0 \\
& \mu (-\tau + \gamma + l_u + 2) = 0 \\
& \omega (-\tau +\frac{3(\gamma - l_u)^2 + \|A\|^2}{C}) = 0 \\
&  \tau \leq 3 l_u ^2\\
& \tau \geq \gamma + l_u + 2\\
& \tau \geq \frac{3(\gamma - l_u)^2 + \|A\|^2}{C} \\
& \lambda, \mu, \omega \geq0
\end{align} 
$$

- From first equation $\tau = \frac{\mu+\omega-\lambda}{2}$
- Then I plug in this into the second, third and fourth equations. But I did not manage to solve that.

Please advise.

Comment: A commonly used approach is to make a case distinction $\lambda=0$ vs. $\lambda>0$ (similarly for the other parameters). This should simplify the computations and since you only have 3 multipliers this leaves you with at most 8 cases to explore.

Comment: Moreover, in the current form your problem does not make any sense.  It reads $\min \max$? Did you mean just $\min$? Also what is the minimization (maximization) over? Is $\theta$ the only free variable? Then the solution is given buy the lower (upper) bound.